# Logic App Response "ActionResponseTimedOut" issue

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

"ActionResponseTimedOut. The execution of template action 'Response' is failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client application and service will be closed and client application will get an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout."

My logic App is wrapped with API Management. This logic app takes max 3 second to execute and it is not at all long running process. Alos I don't want to enable "Asynchronous response" as well.

any suggestion why this timeout is happenning?

Comment: Enable Azure Monitor on API Management and see what kind of error you're getting for the request.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click "Setting" of your "Response" action.
2. Enable "Asynchronous Response"
   [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t3eY.png)
3. Hit save